# Can we use Same Internal IP address in Windows Azure using HNV 2012 Onpremises

Tags: azure

We are looking for a technical advice where we will install Server 2012 R2 Hyper v Host server after completing all its configuration do we use Windows azure as a hosting DR Site for our on premises Live servers.

In addition to that can we get same internal IP address on Azure VM which we will use in our on premises server using HNV ( Network virtualization of Server 2012 R2 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you provide the same IP you'll have problems with routing (depending on how you intend to connect your on-premise environment to your Azure environment).  You can't assign static IP addresses in Azure even when using your own IP address space on a Virtual Network.

Have a read about Azure Virtual Networks and Site-to-Site VPNs.  The rest is standard IPv4 networking logic around addressing and routing.

Comment: I am pretty sure that info is not correct and you can do private static IP addresses in a virtual network.

Comment: Virtual Networks don't support static IP addressing.  This is why you provide an address range when setting up a virtual network - the Azure fabric manages IP allocation via DHCP.  If you switch off a VM it is not guaranteed to come back up with the same IP. [Read about it on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156090.aspx#BKMK_IPAddressDNS)